# XeLaTeX can't turn off small caps

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec

I found a weird issue when using the free typeface [Fontin](http://www.exljbris.com/fontin.html).

```
\documentclass{article} % Default font size and paper size

\usepackage{fontspec} % For loading fonts

\setmainfont{Fontin}

\begin{document}

Here is some text.

\textnormal{Here is some text.}

\textup{Here is some text.}

\textrm{Here is some text.}

\textsf{Here is some text.}

\textsl{Here is some text.}

\textsc{Here is some text.}

\uppercase{Here is some text.}

\lowercase{Here is some text.}

\textbf{Here is some text.}

\textmd{Here is some text.}

\end{document}
```

When I compile with XeLaTeX, most of the text comes out as small-caps:
[image: 2]

If I use LuaLaTeX, however, everything is rendered as expected -- except for the small-caps line:

[image: 3]

I have only encountered this issue with Fontin; other typefaces seem to work as they should. I'm using Arch Linux.

Comment: I just downloaded the font now and tried texlive 2015 xelatex and got [this output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/peURZ.png)

Comment: This font has been problematic for years, but my problems don’t look exactly like yours.  Try this very explicit invocation: `\setmainfont{Fontin}[BoldFont={* Bold},ItalicFont={* Italic},SmallCapsFont={* SmallCaps}]` and `\setsansfont{Fontin Sans}`.

Comment: You can even add `UprightFont={* Regular}` to the list of options.

Comment: I get the output in the question. The warning in ***both*** cases is that small-caps isn't defined and upright is substituted....

Comment: You can try clearing your fontconfig font cache with `fc-cache` then log out and in. If it doesn't suffice consider taking a look at [Font Installation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fonts).

Comment: If I use `\setmainfont{Fontin}[SmallCapsFont={* SmallCaps}]`, the result is what's expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article} % Default font size and paper size
\usepackage{fontspec} % For loading fonts
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont=Fontin]{Fontin-Regular}

\begin{document}
    Here is some text.\par
    \textnormal{Here is some text.} normal\par
    \textup{Here is some text.} up\par
    \textrm{Here is some text.} rm\par
    \textsf{Here is some text.} sf\par
    \textsl{Here is some text.} sl\par
    \textsc{Here is some text.} sc\par
    \uppercase{Here is some text.} uppercase\par
    \lowercase{Here is some text.} lowercase\par
    \textbf{Here is some text.} bf\par
    \textmd{Here is some text.} md
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: On MacTeX2015, it looks like it's necessary to write `\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont={Fontin SmallCaps}]{Fontin}` in order to get everything -- incl. smallcaps, slanted, and bold -- running properly under LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Yes, that depends to the system and the installed fonts. However, I suppose, that you already hadn't the problem with SmallCaps everywhere

Comment: Indeed, I have version `001.000` of the Fontin package, year 2004.

Comment: The problem is the family name of the small caps font: `Family:              Fontin SmallCaps`. It should be `Fontin`.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\setmainfont{Fontin}

 \begin{document}
Here is some text.

\textnormal{Here is some text.}

\textup{Here is some text.}

\textrm{Here is some text.}

\textsf{Here is some text.}

\textsl{Here is some text.}

\textsc{Here is some text.}

\uppercase{Here is some text.}

\lowercase{Here is some text.}

\textbf{Here is some text.}

\textmd{Here is some text.}

\end{document}

\end{document}
```

Produces

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/CYKXcobrm9ju7naSJ-TN2u7nm0r9Xl4MXscfbaqwonTyzHx43NLsXVLw2ovoF6OdSZzICraGVyS1-x9b4okyMERNGFZJgC71albWMNEWSWwj9sd0myp1uZRKgooGLayDc7u2p_MNLTndouW2sqi6B1Bu2frEd4BG32zxW1kMsZPlakHwJNQHkFo6aM5_3Q9noP50-R48WUlPTg0tzp4OAqqhba4TcobUNaZvcdEMeek9HaMtnxNhTVEnxWYLUh11T04_C0oQt9LhaptcjI1qh-9kQYDqb2mgt8v02TbXLbI3W6yzqLf_Wv1TYCBtVOq8hs9AnmwqkP-MfO44QsKVNjGdtzDRYqbCfKxXbk3mdehTuxs_GPMVrWshwJGKuseQpY1TOubbJA4yJ0bq9x3hFcF-zd66os5ByFtN2bCyO2YnBmQZZz5-dzyUiX_rd43lgKjh8UxsPlsvE8MjIHEU8yI7ug7jupBtSoFX0UEmKIOxHrfEFORSsIxXEdboP_IB3SCtXQyF_xxdn9JuCQMQCQSug1qPD24V4ckLxrrvstWSTGDaVi1JW-soYy5JqVXfds2c=w243-h305-no

Comment: That link doesn't work, and it's much better if you take a screenshot and upload via the button just above the answer field.